# How to send a mail between 2 Ubuntu virtual machines in VirtualBox?

Tags: postfix, mail

I have 2 Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machines and I have installed [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) on both of them.

How can I send a mail between them in [localhost](http://whatismyipaddress.com/localhost)?

Answer (score 1):

I assume, this is sort of test environment, without a real DNS/MX/etc settings?
I think you should take a look at https://linux.die.net/man/5/transport. These postfix settings allows you to force the recipient/destination host for some emails. Just setup the destination host for your needs.